# How to install Ubuntu to Windows Vista with or without a usb?

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, downloads, windows-vista

I want to install the latest Ubuntu to my old Windows Vista but don't know which way to go about. I don't have a cd to do the live cd method but I do have a usb but I'm lost from there what should I download and how should I download it, to the pc or to the usb? Am I supposed to wipe my hard drive? Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to wipe Windows Vista and replace with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I can try and point you in the right direction based on some recent experience I have had:

1. Make sure you have a USB stick that is at least 2GB big.
2. Check your BIOS settings and make sure that it is set to boot from USB. It is important to make sure that the USB preference comes before the hard drive in priority.
3. Download the Ubuntu image at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Make sure you pick 64-bit or 32-bit depending on your computer capability.
4. Download a program to burn the image to your USB stick. Look [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/) for the one recommended by Ubuntu. Also see [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for the link on the Ubuntu page.
5. Once the burn is complete, keep the USB stick plugged in and reboot Vista, for the last time!
6. Then follow the instructions during the boot up. Be patient, sometimes it can take some time depending on how fast your machine is.

Note: You may also want to be sure you have backed up all of your files that you want because the default installation will wipe your hard drive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are there any specific system requirements I'll need?